# TWRP restored backup and now "google play services has stopped" pops up every second

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, backup, twrp, google-play-services

**TL;DR** *On turning on pops up "google play services has stopped" and on clicking ok it pops up again after 1/2s so i cant do anything then 1click at a time. Also my account isnt in google play- it asks for new account.*

**Full story**

Samsung S3 I9300.

Had Omnirom. With TWRP did a backup 2 months ago. Tried Neatrom and now i wanted back my system with Omnirom with all backup. So i did clean restore of both System and Data. Clean cache and dalvik cache, Restart, 5min loading and then problem.

*On turning on pops up "google play services has stopped" and on clicking ok it pops up again after 1/2s so i cant do anything then 1click at a time. Also my account isnt in google play- it asks for new account.*

Comment: Try clearing the cache in TWRP.

Comment: Updated that cleaned cache as allways

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with my OnePlus.
This helped:

1. Go to “Settings”
2. Select “Apps”
3. Swipe left until you in the ‘All’ column
4. Click on the 3 dots in top right
5. Select “Reset app preferences”
6. Reboot phone
7. Reselect preferred launcher

via http://blog.forret.com/2015/06/getting-rid-of-google-play-services-has-stopped-on-oneplus/

Comment: Wow. Actually I didn't wanted to clear all settings so I cleared then just that proves settings and cache of Google Play Store and Play services, so one of them clearing helped. Change solution to that and it's accepted! Also if that won't help for some maybe they need also to clear some more or all. But for me only one of these 2 clearing helped!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall `Google Play Services` with for example `titanium backup` and then reinstall `Google Play Services` from `Google Play`.

Comment: Not easy. Slow process couse keeps poping up that error. But why did it actually happen is it knowable?

Comment: I've had that problem too and I never knew why. I think it is just a strange bug. And if helped please accept my answer.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try flashing right google apps aka: GAPPS  to your backup with TWRP. 
It must be corresponding to your backups android versio.

Comment: Tryd restoring all then gapps. Restoring system then gapps then data. System then data then gapps. Allways cleaning cache and dalvik cache between each action. Allways still same error but also icons of desktop lost.